# Schengen visa application in USA but next destination is India

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens

I am in a unique situation,  I am traveling to Italy and applying to Schengen visa in USA. My final destination is India.

H1B valid until Aug 6th, 2019.
Italy travel dates May 16th till May 26th (less than 3 months before my H1B expires)
Next destination - India (I have valid passport)

Will my Schengen visa application it get rejected because my H1B expires?

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Did you get your visa?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a job or your resident permit is about to end, according to immigration officers, you are more likely to overstay. You need to provide proof to overcome that assumption. You can provide the following documents.

- Stable bank statement with enough balance (Do not park funds to inflate it).
- Letter from your current employer stating they intent to renew your visa (if they are doing that).
- Offer letter from your new employer with your stated joining date.

Any additional proof that can overcome the assumption will be helpful. All the best for your application.

Comment: See this also - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53833/schengen-visa-application-rejected-because-my-us-visa-stamp-expires-in-december