# L1 visa expires shortly, and I am applying for a Schengen visa from Houston VFS

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

My L1 visa is set to expire in September and I am applying for a Schengen visa to travel to Europe post my expiration. However, below is my itinerary.
I will be traveling to India before my visa expires and then from India I will be traveling to Europe with my family. And from Europe I will return to India. Also, the reason I am visiting India is for L1 visa extension.
Will my Schengen visa be approved in this case?

Comment: How is your (US, presumably) L1 visa related at all to the story?

Comment: Since I am applying from Houston vfs office, the person at the office was very skeptical about my application since my US Visa is expiring. However, I explained to her that I will be traveling from India and will go back to India from Europe. But she didn’t seem very convinced and told my visa could get rejected. So I wanted to understand if that’s a possibility

Comment: What person at what office?

Comment: The person receiving my schengen application at the vfs office at Houston. I applied for France visa

Comment: There’s always the possibility of a refusal, much less so if you apply *after* your US visa is approved. But no-one can give you the odds of approval vs denial

Comment: You're in the US legally and you intend to go to EU from India and return to India, of which I'm assuming you're a citizen. The fact that you're currently in the US doesn't seem to be relevant at all to me in the context of your visa approval.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica VFS is a service provider for various European countries to provide administrative support services to visa applicants

Comment: @PeterM I am well aware of VFS's identity and role, thanks. I had read the question text too fast, and didn't see that the OP was speaking of the clerk in the VFS office.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen visa application in USA but next destination is India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135322/schengen-visa-application-in-usa-but-next-destination-is-india)

Comment: @mlc Yes, kind of. But I did not provide a letter from my employer stating that I am going for my visa extension. However, I have mentioned it in my cover letter